# OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats

Tags: android, opencv

I am developing an application in whitch i have to take a picture from camera and after that Detect the Edge Square(Like Document page.) in the picture...After a long searching i found OpenCV library to achieve this, i have succesfully imported the java library for android, But problem is that when i call the method of opencv to detect Square(The method is

**Imgproc.findContours(converted, contours,hierarchy,Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,Imgproc.RETR_LIST)**)..it give me the

exception...***OpenCV Error:*** Unsupported format or combination of formats (FindContours support only 8uC1 and 32sC1 images) in _CvContourScanner* cvStartFindContours(void*, CvMemStorage*, int, int, int, CvPoint), file /home/reports/ci/slave/50-SDK/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/contours.cpp, line 196

I am sending u some piece of code-----------------------------------------------------

public void convertImage() {

```
    Mat ori = new Mat();
    Mat converted = new Mat(200, 200, CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(0));

    try {
        ori = Utils.loadResource(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_launcher, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Imgproc.cvtColor(ori,  converted, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 4);  // convert Image to grayscale
    Imgproc.threshold(ori, converted, 50, 250, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C); // threshold the image

    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>(10);
    Mat hierarchy = new Mat(200, 200, CvType.CV_32FC1, new Scalar(0));

    Imgproc.findContours(converted, contours, hierarchy,Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,Imgproc.RETR_LIST);

    ImageView frame = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    Imgproc.cvtColor(converted, converted, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA, 4); // convert Image back to RGB
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(converted.cols(), converted.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);




    frame.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
```

Any Help will be apreciated------------------
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

In 'cvFindCounters' The first argument is the input image; this image should be an 8-bit single-channel image and will be interpreted as binary.
so Instead of passing a 4 channel image , you should be passing a single channel image.

this should work for you.
Imgproc.cvtColor(ori, converted, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY, **1**);

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(ori,  converted, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 1);
Imgproc.cvtColor(converted, converted, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA, 1);
```

instead of

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(ori,  converted, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 4);
Imgproc.cvtColor(converted, converted, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA, 4);
```

Because you need to use 1 channel.

Answer (score 0):

First load the bitmap as -

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                       R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Then convert the bitmap to Mat -

```
Mat m = new Mat();
Utils.bitmapToMat(icon, m);
Imgproc.cvtColor(m, m, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 1);
```

Perform your threshold and findcontours as above..basic idea is to convert Bitmap to Mat which is single channel..